# Looping through an array of objects to display something specific

Tags: javascript

I have multiple objects, which represent different TV shows. They are stored in an array. Given a specific attribute, `x`, I want to loop through the array and only display the names of the television shows with given attribute, `x`.

For example, let's say I want to display Action TV shows. Right now, I can only find objects that not only share the genre, but also the duration and rating (they are exactly equal).

How do I display a item in the array depending on only one attribute?

Comment: try looking at the .filter() function, write some code, post it if it doesn't work and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Do you have a sample data format on the objects of TV shows?

Comment: and maybe show us what the array looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the Array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method should give you what you want. Here's a start:

```
var filteredFilms = films.filter(function(film) { 
 return parseInt(film.duration) > 150 && film.genre === 'Crime'; 
});
```

Comment: I don't really understand where i should place this variable and how to output the result of it.

Comment: Where I've hardcoded values (150, 'Crime') you need to replace with the contents of the appropriate input field. The result is an array of your filtered films array. What you do with it is up to you, but you can inspect the results in the console :- console.log('Filtered films:', filteredFilms);